# Any difference between "siblings" in /proc/cpuinfo and "threads" in intel official documentations?

Tags: central-processing-unit, threads

`/proc/cpuinfo` provides such info:

```
...
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 63
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v3 @ 2.40GHz
stepping    : 2
microcode   : 59
cpu MHz     : 2397.161
cache size  : 20480 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 16  <---------------------------
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 8   <---------------------------
apicid      : 2
initial apicid  : 2
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
...
```

Intel provides this:

[image]

https://ark.intel.com/products/83356/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2630-v3-20M-Cache-2_40-GHz

Why is terminology different? I usually heard term thread, not a sibling. E.g. "Single-thread program"